# Sort pairs — first elements by order of appearance, second elements numerically

Tags: matrix, sorting

I have a long table in this form:

```
A = {{a, 1}, {c, 2}, {b, 5}, {c, 1}, {a, 14}, {b, 7}, {b, 10}, {c, 6}, {a, 4}}
```

and I want to order it by the second column, but first all with an "a" in the first element should be ordered. And then by order of appearance. It should look like this:

> `{{a, 1},{a, 4},{a, 14},{c, 1},{c, 2},{c, 6},{b, 5},{b, 7},{b, 10}}`

`SortBy[A, #[[2]] &]` would sort the second column, ignoring the first.

Any ideas? Maybe a for-loop?

Comment: So, you don't want `SortBy[A, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}]`?

Comment: Why don't you use just `Sort[A]` ?

Comment: If you want it as in the OP, just try `Sort /@ GatherBy[A, First]`.

Comment: Thank you! `Sort /@ GatherBy[A, First]` was what I wanted. The other two answers would also sort the first element alphabetically. I wanted it by order of appearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Artes' comment:

```
A = {{a, 1}, {c, 2}, {b, 5}, {c, 1}, {a, 14}, {b, 7}, {b, 10}, {c, 6}, {a, 4}};
Sort /@ GatherBy[A, First]
```

> `{{{a, 1}, {a, 4}, {a, 14}}, {{c, 1}, {c, 2}, {c, 6}}, {{b, 5}, {b, 7}, {b, 10}}}`

Comment: To get the specified output you need to include a `Flatten`: `Flatten[Sort /@ GatherBy[A, First], 1]`

Comment: Or `Catenate` instead of `Flatten`.